# The meaning of $\mathbb R^n$ in $f:\mathbb R^n \rightarrow \mathbb R$

Tags: functions, notation

I'm just making my way in Math and I apologise for the ease of this question. I don't understand what $\mathbb R^n$ in $f(x):\mathbb R^n \rightarrow \mathbb R$ actually means.

Comment: This just means that the domain of the function is $R^n$, so it is defined for n-tuples of numbers.

Comment: @user84413 Thanks. So, the function accepts n numbers and results in only one number?

Comment: That's right; its inputs are an ordered set of n numbers, and its outputs are just 1 number.  As a simple example, we could let $f:R^{2}\rightarrow R$ be defined by $f(x,y)=x^2+5y$.

Comment: @user84413 Thank you very much.

Comment: you will have to spend some time on this, but what it means is that  the function's input/domain is n dimensional real number and output is 1 dimensional real number

Comment: @Vikram Sorry if this question is inane, but is an n-dimensional real number the same as n numbers which are real?

Comment: @Jojo Yes, it's an ordered collection of n real numbers. In general, an element of $R^n$ is denoted by $(x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n)$ where the $x_i$ are real numbers.

Comment: @user84413 Thanks again. I'll be sure to vote your posts up once I get the required number of points to do so.

Answer (score 2):

<sup>Compiled from comments by  [user84413](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/909970/simple-function-notation#comment1877656_909970)</sup>

This just means that the domain of the function is $\mathbb R^n$, so it is defined for $n$-tuples of numbers.

Its inputs are an ordered set of $n$ numbers, and its outputs are just $1$ number.  As a simple example, we could let $f:\mathbb R^{2}\rightarrow \mathbb R$ be defined by $f(x,y)=x^2+5y$.

In general, an element of $\mathbb R^n$ is denoted by $(x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n)$ where the $x_i$ are real numbers.